# Internal link deleted after downloading PDF with html2pdf in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, pdf, html2pdf

I am using Vue JS and html2pdf to download dynamic content. When i am trying to link to a div inside my component with an anchor tag it's working perfectly on my local.

But when i download the document there is a link in the document but it's not scrolling to my supposing div.

I would like to know to if it's possible to do this?

```
<div id="app" ref="document"> 
   <a href="#test">
      Jump to the part of the page with the “test” id
   </a>
   <div class="card" id="preview">
      <div class="card-block">
         <p id="test">blablabla.....</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

My function to export the pdf:

```
 async exportToPDF() {
      await html2pdf(this.$refs.document, {
        margin: 1,
        filename: "document.pdf",
        image: { type: "jpeg", quality: 0.98 },
        html2canvas: { dpi: 192, letterRendering: true },
        jsPDF: { unit: "in", format: "letter", orientation: "landscape" }
      });
    },
```

It is possible still have the same link who is going here the the div with the id="test"?

At the end i would like to make a table of content in a dynamic way.

Thank you for reading :)

Have a nice day!

Comment: So is it possible to what i want to do? Can you give me a part of code for me to understand please? 
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I believe there should be `enableLinks` option available in `html2pdf` library. Something like this:

Ref: https://ekoopmans.github.io/html2pdf.js/#options

```
html2pdf(element, {
    enableLinks: true
    // ... other options
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reply.
After looking online and check different code i didn't find any solution. Normal links are working but not internal links even with enableLinks!

I am not sure it's possible.

Comment: did you find a solution for this eventually?